# Problems with page layout breaking on mobile devices (or when window resized)

Tags: html, css, layout, mobile

I'm having a problem with a webpage (located at http://launchpadtoys.com/monkeygram/) breaking when viewed on mobile devices, including an iPhone 4S and Galaxy Nexus at least. The page renders correctly in the major desktop browsers so I'm unsure what the solution could be. Here's the problem I'm having: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFarX.png

Comment: Your background is acting strange in desktop too, are you using jQuery to resize anything? I just took a quick look but your wrapper gets smaller than the body when resizing.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed the weird shrinking of the wrapper as well. I'm only using jQuery on this pagefor the slideshow inside the iPhone at the top of the page.

Comment: Is it still breaking? I see you fixed the background, so it looks like it's done

Comment: it's still breaking, i actually had to replace the live version with what was previously old_index (that version is practically identical to my eyes but doesn't have the same problem). the broken version is still online at http://launchpadtoys.com/monkeygram/new-monkeygram-promo-page.php if you can think of anything else that could be causing the problem. i've spent a couple hours the past two days debugging in firebug and i'm failing to find anything that would cause the wrapper to behave that way

Comment: page is a 404 for me. I assume thats just for me?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />` in the head section of your page.

Comment: I actually already tried both this and setting the width to explicit values. Setting it to be 1300 pixels wide seem to be a temporary fix but isn't ideal. I have an older version of the page still online at http://launchpadtoys.com/monkeygram/old_index.php which doesn't have this issue if that helps.

Comment: After a quick look at your CSS, I think maybe `#lbCaption, #lbNumber{margin-right: 71px;}` is breaking your page on smaller browsers.

Comment: While both lbCaption and lbNumber are referenced once each in the code, their respective DIVs both also have display:none and therefore shouldn't have any effect on how the layout is displayed. I also removed those styles just in case and nothing changed.